# Im trying to run mvn quarkus:dev in docker container, but it dosent seem to work properly

Tags: docker, maven, docker-compose, quarkus

mvn quarkus:dev works as in i get the quarkus logo and Listening on: http://localhost:8080
but when i try to connect to localhost:8080 it fails and i get "connection was reset", am i missing something?

this is my setup

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  planner:
    container_name: planner
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/planner/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ../ezuro/planner/src/main/java:/planner/src/main/java
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:latest

WORKDIR /planner

COPY ./ezuro/planner .

CMD mvn quarkus:dev
```

i tried connecting to quarkus with other docker containers and that also didnt work so im out of ideas, i just need so the container can be connected to and hot reload works

Comment: Can I ask why you want to use Quarkus dev mode in a docker container?

Comment: It would be pretty nice to just docker-compose up for the whole tech stack for development. But the problem started when tried to connect to quarkus running on localhost from docker and it just didint work, im on linux nixos and none of the solutions i found for linux worked so i thought it just do it the other way around and have quarkus in a docker container but that also dosent work so idk what to do now lol

Comment: @Winter Wolf Have you tried setting `quarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0` in application.properties, or check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add host in application.properties, or define custom profile for docker (applicaiton-docker.properties)

Here is working example:

application.properties

```
quarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine
COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code
CMD mvn clean compile
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  quarkus-app:
    container_name: quarkus-app
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5005:5005" # Debugging port
    working_dir: /code
    entrypoint: [ "mvn", "clean", "quarkus:dev" ]
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

EDIT: Repo with example project https://github.com/bgizdov/quarkus-3.2-dev-mode-docker

just run `docker-compose up`

Comment: holy sheet, that solved it, realy big thanks, sadly i cant upvote i dont have 15 reputation, but im very grateful.

Comment: I am happy it is working :)